# How did Facebook implement the chat sidebar?

Tags: facebook, sidebar

I'm trying to understand how Facebook implements the chat sidebar. It seems to stay there even as I change pages. For example, if I select some text inside the sidebar, then click to go to another Facebook page, the text remains selected. It's as if it was a separate frame, but when I look at the code, it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a container DOM element called "fb_content", its content is replaced through straight-forward AJAX or more technically [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest). (Although when for example you enter an app, the entire page is refreshed.) To update the address bar they use the [JavaScript History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Answer (score 4):

All requests are made trough AJAX calls. Only "content" container is replaced when needed.

You don't actually "go" to another page. Just the "content" div gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Zeno and lericson said (fb_content gets updated via ajax), the address bar also gets updated while maintaining the history (if you press back/forward).